# Is there any way to create Ruby Struct from struct in string-form?

Tags: ruby, string, struct

I have to know, if I'll make string from struct (using .to_s) is there any way to make it struct back ? I wonder if there is some helper class or something.

My case of use is to hold or info in struct, then send it through the internet and build a struct from it on the other side.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: give us a sample input and expected output too.

Comment: You better use more standard medium, such as JSON. Write methods to convert your struct to/from JSON and you're good.

Comment: @iAmRubuuu whatever u can imagine ;) just needed example

Comment: @SergioTulentsev seems legit, i totally forgot about alternatives :) Thanks

Comment: @SergioTulentsev can you join here? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27184/ruby-conceptual

Answer (score 3):

To flush out the other options given by @Semyon above:

- **YAML** 
   Portable, but rather Ruby specific in its use. Supports serializing any Ruby object in a special way that only Ruby can really understand. If you want portability between Rubies but not languages, YAML is the way to go:

  ```
  require 'yaml'
  obj = [1,2,3]
  YAML.dump(obj) #=> Something like "---\n- 1\n- 2\n- 3\n"
  YAML.load(YAML.dump(o)) #=> [1,2,3]
  ```
- **JSON** 
   JSON is the most widely recognized and portable data standard for these kinds of things. Portable between Rubies, languages, and systems.

  ```
  require 'json'
  obj = [1,2,3]
  obj.to_json #=> "[1,2,3]"
  JSON.load("[1,2,3]") #=> [1,2,3]
  ```

Both, unlike `Marshal`, are human readable.

Answer (score 2):

String that you get from `struct.to_s` is made for inspection only. To transfer your struct you will need to serialize it on the one side and deserialize it from the other side. There are a variety of formats including JSON, YAML and Marshal. The last one produces non human-readable byte streams but it is the most easy to use:

```
Person = Struct.new(:first_name, :last_name)
me = Person.new("Semyon", "Perepelitsa")
p data = Marshal.dump(me)
"\x04\bS:\vPerson\a:\x0Ffirst_nameI\"\vSemyon\x06:\x06ET:\x0Elast_nameI\"\x10Perepelitsa\x06;\aT"

# on the other side
p Marshal.load(data)
#<struct Person first_name="Semyon", last_name="Perepelitsa">
```